# Different physiological effect of beer and wine?

Tags: alcohol

I wonder if it's possible for beer to cause you to be sleepier than wine with the same amount of alcohol in it? And if so, what would be the cause?

Comment: An interesting question. I’m pretty sure the alcohol effects are the same, but usually a beer is more volume and makes you feel fuller.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There might me several effects that lead to beer being more sleep-inducing, but one of the most important seems to be: the hops.

Hops has a sedative effect and there are even [papers on this topic](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3399866/), where non alcoholic beer is investigated for it's sleep enhancement effects.

Comment: Very interesting. I appreciate your use of “might” and “seems” as this is just one, small study.